# When is Context instantiated in android?

Tags: android

I have a Dashboard Activity in my android application, and my app also contains an DBHelper class. I noticed that if I were to try to instantiate the DBHelper in the Dashboard Activity(which is the initial activity) it does not work. It tells me that the context is null and gives me a nullpointerexception.

However, this issue does not occur when the DBHelper is instantiated outside the first activity. Why is this? Is context somehow not instantiated in the initial activity of android?

Edit: Would like to add, that I have tried to initialize context in the activity's onCreate method but this is to no avail.

Here's the dashboard fragment:

```
package azynias.study.Fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import azynias.study.Activities.FrontActivity;
import azynias.study.DataHandlers.TierDBHandler;
import azynias.study.R;


public class FrontFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView progItemsDue;
    private TextView progTitle;

    private TierDBHandler tierDBHandler = TierDBHandler.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    private void init(View view) {
        progTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_progress_dashb_frag);
        progItemsDue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.items_overdue_dashb_frag);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_front, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        init(view);
        initProgCard();
    }

    public void initProgCard() {
        int due = 5;

        progTitle.setText("PROGRESS");
        progItemsDue.setText(due + " items are due today.");
    }

    public FrontFragment() {

    }
}
```

And the activity for the dashboard:

```
package azynias.study.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import azynias.study.DataHandlers.TierDBHandler;
import azynias.study.Fragments.FrontFragment;
import azynias.study.R;

public class FrontActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front);

        mContext = this.getApplicationContext();

        FrontFragment frontFrag = new FrontFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.dashboard_material_frag, frontFrag);

        ft.commit();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        //  return instance.getApplicationContext();
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an Android expert, but I would guess that the framework is handling the `DBHelper` for you, possibly using dependency injection to make it available.

Comment: Context is an  Abstract class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ If that's the case, how do I get around initializing my DBHelper class in the first activity? If it's abstract, shouldn't it work if I implement the getContext method in the initial activity and make sure its initialized?

Comment: If you need a context in your Activity do not declare it in the member variable directly but within `onCreate()`

Comment: Show me the code of DashboardActivity

Comment: Kindly post code snippet of Dashboard activity where context is null.

Comment: I've added in the code for both the fragment and activity. I've tried several methods to get the context such as getContext() or getActivity().getContext() in both the frag and activity and both say that context is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if I wanted to get a reference to the context, it had to be when the fragment was attached to the activity. There was no valid reference at the time which explains the error.

Here is the code that fixes it inside my fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        tierDBHandler = TierDBHandler.getInstance(getActivity());
    }
```

It seems that reading more into the lifecycles of activities and fragments would have helped here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using getApplicationContext() in the Dashboardactivity? What does it return?

The Context gets initialized as soon as your application starts. i.e. before the application.oncreate() method. So I think the reason for context is null may be different here.